Hololens2 activate "Simulation Control Mode" inside hololens app
My friend and I are playing around with Hololens2. We discovered this "Control Mode" that can pass the value "Simulation" to stop recognise scene/gesture/etc. or "Default" to restore the sensors.
Reference to Control Mode
This calls are set inside the Device Portal. Can anyone suggest a way to code this "switch" inside our app code build with Unity and VS, like a C# function called by some trigger?

The most similar thing we could find is some REST calls to the device portal, but this is available only with the portal active and an external script such as this wrapper. We would find a way to have this mode switching using the hololens standalone without connecting to the portal. (and have quite no experience with REST calls)
How the device portal tells the hololens to switch the mode? Do you know anything about that?
Thank you for any suggestion

Everything in the Windows Device Portal is built on top of REST API. Thus, you can also try the Device portal REST API. However, please note Device Portal is a developer tool and is not to be used in applications deployed to your organization.

Thank you @JayZuo, do you know how to have this effect coded in my app without the device portal involved at all? Some example or reference (or some document that states this as impossible)?
